# How to traverse over JSON object

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, python-requests

I am getting following response from an API, I want to extract Phone Number from this object in Python. How can I do that?

```
    {
"ParsedResults": [
    {
        "TextOverlay": {
            "Lines": [
                {
                    "Words": [
                        {
                            "WordText": "+971555389583", //this field
                            "Left": 0,
                            "Top": 5,
                            "Height": 12,
                            "Width": 129
                        }
                    ],
                    "MaxHeight": 12,
                    "MinTop": 5
                }
            ],
            "HasOverlay": true,
            "Message": "Total lines: 1"
        },
        "TextOrientation": "0",
        "FileParseExitCode": 1,
        "ParsedText": "+971555389583 \r\n",
        "ErrorMessage": "",
        "ErrorDetails": ""
    }
],
"OCRExitCode": 1,
"IsErroredOnProcessing": false,
"ProcessingTimeInMilliseconds": "308",
"SearchablePDFURL": "Searchable PDF not generated as it was not requested."**strong text**}
```

Comment: in python, json (that looks like `{key:value}` pairs are called dictionaries. And python comes with a `json` library that readily converts a json string into a python dictionary. That should help you get started. Look up one or two tutorials if you have to, you should catch up to speed fairly quick.

Comment: You have arrays along the way. You have to know if you interested in just first occurrence an what if there is more than one line or word.

Comment: I just want  "WordText": "+971555389583", this line

Comment: The sample JSON in your question is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the API response to a variable. Let's call it `response`.

Now convert the JSON string to a Python dictionary using the `json` module.

```
import json

response_dict = json.loads(response)
```

Now traverse through the `response_dict` to get the required text.

```
phone_number = response_dict["ParsedResults"][0]["TextOverlay"]["Lines"][0]["Words"][0]["WordText"]
```

Wherever the dictionary value is an array, `[0]` is used to access the first element of the array. If you want to access all elements of the array, you will have to loop through the array.

Answer (score 1):

You have to parse the resulting stirng into a dictionary using the library `json`, afterwards you can traverse the result by looping over the json structure like this:

```
import json

raw_output = '{"ParsedResults": [ { "Tex...' # your api response
json_output = json.loads(raw_output)

# iterate over all lists
phone_numbers = []

for parsed_result in json_output["ParsedResults"]:
    for line in parsed_result["TextOverlay"]["Lines"]:
        # now add all phone numbers in "Words"
        phone_numbers.extend([word["WordText"] for word in line["Words"]])

print(phone_numbers)
```

You may want to check if all keys exist within that process, depending on the API you use, like

```
# ...
for line in parsed_result["TextOverlay"]["Lines"]:
    if "Words" in line: # make sure key exists
        phone_numbers.extend([word["WordText"] for word in line["Words"]])
# ...
```